# Can issetuid() be cleared for a child process?

Tags: permissions, security, users, process

I have a wrapper script `A` which is calling program `B`. `A` must be invoked as root so some initial setup can happen. After that, `A` calls setuid() and setgid() to reduce its own privileges, for safety and security. Then, `A` invokes `B`.

The problem is that `B` exhibits undesirable behavior if and only if `A` has called setuid()/setgid() before invoking `B`. This does not happen when I invoke `B` directly as different users via `sudo -u xxx -g xxx`. As far as I can tell (correct me if I am wrong), the only way `B` could know that `A` has changed the user is via the `issetuid()` syscall (I've checked the environment variables; they match).

**How can I clear this bit, so that `B` behaves normally?** It seems that the use of issetuid() is something about keeping track of whether the process is "tainted", i.e. carries artifacts from a less privileged environment (?). But I've *reduced* my privileges, not elevated them! And on top of that, I've scrubbed my env vars anyway!

Beyond the very terse man page on issetuid(), I can find almost nothing about this syscall/magical program state. Can anyone lend a better understanding?

Comment: In which package does issetuid (header files, documentation, library) live in? I can't find it on my systems, so I assume it is not in libc6-dev or libstd++6-4.6-dev or similar. You can find out the package name automatically with a command like: `dpkg -S $(man -w issetuid)`.

Comment: This could be better suited to [StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com) or even [SuperUser](http://Superuser.com)

Comment: FWIK setuid bit on script files won't work due to security reasons. Google `suid script security` may help.

Comment: There is no `issetuid` syscall. Nor is it a function in the C library. I have no idea where you found a manpage for it; neither `man` nor Google can. Further, *every* non-root process has a setuid (or similar) in its history, as init starts as root and spawns them all.

Comment: I think it might be OpenBSD or cygwin thing, but I haven't found a good explanation of how it is supposed to work or which package has it in Ubuntu.

Comment: If @trbabb doesn't provide more information, at least about what provides `issetuid`, then this question is probably unanswerable and should be closed as not-a-real-question (or as too-localized). It can always be reopened if the information is eventually provided.

Comment: @trbabb None of us seem to be able to find anything about an `issetuid` function. Is it possible you mean [`issetugid`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man2/issetugid.2freebsd.html)? Your description, especially the use of the adjective *tainted*, comports with the description in that function's manpage, and the function it similar to what you seem to have in mind, though it also returns true if the process is setgid (even if not also setuid).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without more information ( such as the name of A and B software ), this is hard to diagnose.

However, I would look at the environment variable, there is surely one that was not cleaned by A and that is cleaned by sudo.